# get current child element jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how I can manipulate the child span of a parent with a certain class when looping over multiple elements
The structure looks like this

```html
<div class="parent">
  <span>i want to change this text (uniquely) per item</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span>i want to change this text (uniquely) per item</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <span>i want to change this text (uniquely) per item</div>
</div>
```

I currently have this which allows me to change the text of the div but not of the span. If someone could for didactic reasons show me how to alter the span with jquery ***and*** regular javascript that would help me a lot, since I come across a lot of loops.

```js
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

var somearray = [400,600];

$j('.parent').each(function() {

    num = this.getAttribute('data-rowid');

    span = this.getElementsByClassName('parent');// <--- i want to know how to select the current span with jquery and regular javascript
    
    $j(span).text(somearray[num]);
    
});
```

Comment: It's **well worth** your time to spend a hour or two reading through [the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com) beginining to end. It really only takes that long, and it pays you back that time almost immediately.

Comment: I will do sir, I greatly appreciate the help. Sometimes we want to take off before we know how to fly :) I'll read it before I make any new post on jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find):

```
var span = $j(this).find("span");
```

or with that *specific* HTML, you could use `.children().first()`:

```
var span = $j(this).children().first();
```

...but that's fragile, if you add something before the span it'll break.

---

Side note: Note that I added `var` so that we were declaring `span`. Without it, you were falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) by not declaring your variables. You'll want to declare `num` as well.

Comment: Thanks Crowder! May I assume you declare the variable outside the loop? or would that be impossible due to the use of "this"

Comment: @rinserepeat: It depends entirely on how long you want those variables. :-) `$.each` is making a call to your anonymous function, so if you only want the variables *during* that loop iteration (function call), declare them within the function and they'll be nicely scoped to just there. If you want them afterward, declare them outside it.

Comment: ah ok great, so just to be sure I would be able declare the variable with the use of "this" outside the loop. and ones I use that variable inside the loop "this" will know what to do?

Comment: @rinserepeat: `this` has nothing whatsoever to do with variables or variable declarations. `this` is effectively a hidden function argument, particularly the way jQuery uses it. Note that the `this` within calls to your `each` callback function will be different from the `this` outside it, but that doesn't have any impact or relation to your *variables*.

Comment: Thanks, I will follow your advise and read the API, and test your code out. Cheers for the help!

Comment: @rinserepeat: Anytime. :-) Nice to meet someone interested in learning, not just being a script kiddie.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();
var somearray = [400,600];

$j('.parent').each(function() {
    var num = $j(this).attr('data-rowid');
    $j(this).find('span').text(somearray[num]);
});
```